# ¿Como puedo hacer validaciones con if de campos para subir un archivo?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo una pantalla donde hay un boton que abre un dialog, en ese dialog se encuentra un multifilememorybuffer el cual abre un boton para subir archvios de tipo pdf y xml, lo que me estan solicitando hacer es que valide los campos del xml antes de subirlo y un compañero me dijo que las validaciones de ese xml se pueden hacer con if en java y springboot

[image: Subir factura xml]

Comment: Y cual es la pregunta/problema o duda?

Comment: no le creas abunda la gente chismosa, es mas facil con las anotaciones del api de validaciones de Java :3

Comment: @RuslanLópez me podrias explicar como lo puedo hacer con esa api

Comment: definitivamente si. Haz tu pregunta y sin problemas... de hecho creo que ya hay varias de eso te recomiendo revisarlas primero :)

Comment: @RuslanLópez Lo que pasa es que no se donde debe ir la validacion no comprendo como validar

Comment: pues intenta y si no te funciona nos cuentas en otra pregunta